# Knockout unable to process binding - not defined

Tags: knockout.js

I inherited a project using Knockout `^3.1.0`.  I need to build out some features.  I've never used Knockout.

Each view has a view model that's called from the main view model with `init(model)`.

The properties are initialized at the beginning of the init and used in the view with no issues. For instance:

```
model.entities = ko.observableArray([]);
model.hasEntities = ko.observable(false);
```

Are initialized as such and used without error in a containerless binding like this:

```
<!-- ko if: hasEntities -->
<!-- ko foreach: { data: entities, as: 'entity' } -->
```

So I initialize my new properties the same place/way:

```
  model.numberOfColumns = ko.observable(2);

  model.columnGenerator = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.range(0, model.numberOfColumns());
  }, model);
```

and use it as such:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: columnGenerator, as: 'index' } -->
```

and get this error:

> knockout.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:columnGenerator,as:'index'} }"
>   Message: columnGenerator is not defined

I've searched the MANY questions relating to this error and none have helped.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the full error message

Comment: done (must type 11 char to post comment)

Comment: Probably because `<!-- ko foreach: { data: columnGenerator, as: 'index' } -->` is in a different *scope* than `$root`. Try `{ data: $root.columnGenerator, as: 'index' }` Or include the full relevant HTML portion.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried that a bunch of times previously and got another error.  I just did it to post the error and everything worked.  So weird.  Maybe it was something else I fixed.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: columnGenerator, as: 'index' } -->
```

Is interpreted in a different *scope* than the `$root` scope (where `columnGenerator` is defined).

Try this instead:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: $root.columnGenerator, as: 'index' } -->
```

See [Binding-Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: I guess my only question is 'why are the other bindings working without the `$root.` prefix?'

Comment: @MayNotBe, Because unless you're changing scope, your scope is the `$root` scope. If you'll include more of your HTML we'll be able to see why / when your scope is changing (probably due to `with` or `foreach`).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Just realized the reason it hadn't been working was because I wasn't clearing my browser cache.  SMH